# What is the standard syntax for hyperlink in reStructuredText: `Foo`_ or Foo_?

Tags: standards, markup, restructuredtext

http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#external-hyperlink-targets shows this example:

```
External hyperlinks, like Python_.

.. _Python: http://www.python.org/
```

But http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#external-links shows this example:

```
This is a paragraph that contains `a link`_.

.. _a link: https://domain.invalid/
```

I am trying to understand which of these two syntaxes are correct and work with all restructuredtext renderers.

Should I use:

```
Foo_
```

to refer to a hyperlink?

Or should I use:

```
`Foo`_
```

to refer to a hyperlink?

Comment: You need the backticks when you have *multiple words* as part of one hyperlink, otherwise how would it distinguish whether the first example should make `Python` or `like Python` or `hyperlinks, like Python`, or ... the link text?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What you are saying makes sense. I see the need for a special syntax using backticks to select a phrase consisting of whitespace as the hypertext. Is this usage documented somewhere in the reStructuredText documentation?

Comment: It's in the docs you've already linked to, right at the top: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup

Comment: I personally prefer the [inline syntax](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#external-links) because it gives me control over the label for the hyperlink, and the URL is closer to the text instead of at the end of a page or section. I'm more likely to visually inspect for updated links while reading narrative text, although I also run `make linkcheck`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct. The syntax for a hyperlink is just an underscore `_`. Backticks are required when the name for the hyperlink contains spaces. Otherwise, both are acceptable. Technically speaking, the backticks are called a "grouping syntax".

It is common practice just to include backticks even if the name for the hyperlink doesn't contain spaces. This is because it's not always immediately understood whether a lone `_` is a typo for a phrase that should containing an underscore or a hyperlink. The ``` ``_ ``` syntax, however, is known to be a hyperlink in reST.